# CoreData - creating new entity - Why don't you need to save this?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, swift3

I figured you can create new entities (in `swift 3`) like this:

`let person = Person(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
person.name = "Some Name"`

This seems to be it. It saves the new person permanently (I think so, at least).

Why don't you need to call `saveContext()`of AppDelegate. swift (or `persistentContainer.viewContext.save()` which is basically the same, right?)?

Every time you change some `entity`, you need to save it. Why isn't this the case when creating new `entities`?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: How have you tested that you don't need to save?

Comment: I'm using the book "Core data by tutorials". In one chapter, exactly this is the case. Also, I tested it by killing the app and restarting it (and I did make sure that the data isn't always inserted when the app starts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments on your question, you ARE calling `saveContext()`.

Go into your `AppDelegate` and check out `applicationWillTerminate`, `saveContext()` is called there.

In short, if you want to persist the data then yes, you need to call `saveContext()`

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. In the book, it says it gets saved immediately after the new entries have been created. That's a bit misleading.

Comment: It IS stored in the context immediately, but it won't be persisted until saved. Also if you have a `ManagedObjectContext` that is a child to the main context then when you save the child it will be saved into the main context. But NOT persisted until you save that main context as that is whats hooked up to the persistent coordinator

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure, the book meant the actual persistent saving, not the storing. That's the reason I was confused

Comment: Which book are you using?

Answer (score 1):

for your anser you have to understand the Core Data stack

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH25-SW1

Changes that you make to your managed objects are not committed to the parent store until you save the context.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as well. But the book was kind of misleading regarding this. That's why I asked this question here